# cassandra add column if not exists

Tags: cassandra, database-schema, cql3

I need to insert a new column into an existing column family via a CQL script.

I want to do something like:

```
alter COLUMNFAMILY rules ADD rule_template text IF NOT EXISTS;
```

How can I achieve this purely in CQL script?

Comment: You can file a feature request at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There is no optional "if not exists" for altering column families (tables). As a workaround you could just execute the alter command and ignore the error if the column already exists. There shouldn't be any harm in it, other than the error message.

Comment: Yea that works. My assumption was that an error would halt the script mid flow. I guess the lesson here is to try before you cry.