# How to alter table add column if column not exists in cassandra?

Tags: python, cassandra

I have some predefined columns in a Cassandra table/column family. I also get a another JSON /dictionary object which has key:value pair which are not predefined and hence were not included in the create table statement (I am using cql3 library on python). I want to add this data to my Cassandra table, I want a unique key in the json object to become a new column. If a key which has already been made a column is present in the json, Cassandra should just reject that query without throwing an exception. It throws an exception if I try to simply alter the table to add a pre existing column. Is there an alter table add column if column doesn't exists type query or should I handle it through exception handling?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cassandra add column if not exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25728944/cassandra-add-column-if-not-exists)

Answer (score 1):

Currently there isn't a mechanism for doing this. The `IF NOT EXISTS` functionality is currently [only for *CREATE* and *DROP* modification statements](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cql-in-cassandra-2-0) (take a look at Conditional schema modifications).

I would remodel the table to allow what you call the *key* to be in a column (as in column of a table) and use a collection to store its various values ending up with something like:

```
 key    | date_added                           | values
--------+--------------------------------------+-------
 1      | e64d8be0-4f2a-11e4-b409-138283d4b034 | ['item1', 'item2']
 7      | e64d8be0-4f2a-11e4-b409-138283d4b034 | ['item1', 'item5']
 1      | e64d8be0-4f2a-11e4-b409-138283d4b034 | ['item4']
```

On a side note, if you have a `IF NOT EXISTS` alter statement every time you're carrying out a query you would incur a lot of overhead verifying that the row doesn't exist.

Comment: I am assuming, alter table is a constant time operation in Cassandra.